# Raspberry Pi won't boot after restart during upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, raspberry-pi, apt

I ran `sudo apt upgrade` on my Raspberry Pi (running Ubuntu Mate) over ssh. The connection timed out, but when I reconnected and tried continuing the upgrade, I got an error, so I tried to reboot, but now the Pi won't boot up at all. The ACT LED is blinking, but all I get on the screen is the rainbow square.

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing would be to make a new sd card with an up to date Ubuntu Mate and copy over all your user data using an SD card reader. Presumably just pi's home:

```
/home/pi
```

If you only have a windows system and cannot read that SD card, just get a second SD card, put the updated image on it, put it into your RPi and use the SD card reader with the usb ports on the RPi.

Comment: I was thinking of that, but I don't know which directories to copy over (not everything I need is in my home directory), and how to make sure that there are no ownership issues once everything's copied.